# How to disable some specific columns from edit in react material react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-react-table

By default with [Material React Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/editing#table-editing-mode) all fields are editable. I would like be able to make some read-only. However I cannot see it in the documentation anywhere.

```
  import MaterialReactTable from 'material-react-table'  

  const columns = [
    { headerName: 'ID', accessorKey: 'categoryId', width: 20, },
    { headerName: 'Name', accessorKey: 'categoryName', width: 220, editable: true },
    {
      headerName: 'Game System',
      width: 220,
      accessorKey: 'gameSystemId',
      type: 'numeric',
      editable: true,
    },
  ]

  <MaterialReactTable columns={columns} loading={loading} data={allCategories} onEditingRowSave={onRowAdd} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [official example for conditionally enabling editing](https://www.material-react-table.dev/?path=/story/features-editing-examples--enable-editing-conditionally)

```
  const columns = [
    { header: 'ID', accessorKey: 'categoryId', enableEditing: false|true },
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the headerName editable to false like this.

```
 { headerName: 'ID', accessorKey: 'categoryId', width: 20, editable: false },
  { headerName: 'Name', accessorKey: 'categoryName', width: 220, editable: true }
```

Comment: Look closer at the posted code.

Comment: That would work for material-table, but sadly not for material-react-table.